# Combine Multiple Ng-Repeats

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I have an html structure where each children have different length values:

```
<div ng-repeat='element in treeView'>
    <div ng-repeat='element1 in element.children'>
        <div ng-repeat='element2 in element1.children'>
            <div ng-repeat='element3 in element2.children'>
                <div ng-repeat='element4 in element3.children'>
                    <div ng-repeat='element5 in element4.children'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont like multiple `ng-repeat`.

How to re structure the code?

Comment: why don't `ng-repeat="element in treeview.children.children.children.children.children"`?

Comment: Do you only want to print out data in the `<div ng-repeat='element5 in element4.children'></div>`??

Answer (score 0):

To create DOM nodes for all children of treeView recursively you can create a new component.

Example usage:

```
<your-directive elements="vm.elements"></your-directive>
```

Component code:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
  .component('yourDirective', {
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    bindings: {
      elements: '='
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  });
```

Template code:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in vm.elements">
    <your-directive ng-if="vm.elements.children.length > 0" elements="vm.elements"></your-directive>
</div>
```

Note: I haven't tested this code but with a little tinkering you should get this to work.